# Picasso lib end whit "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$layout"

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

Picasso 2.5.2 and appcompat-v7:22.1.1 is not compatable.

Android Studio 1.2
Adding picasso-2.5.2.jar to my project lead to this exception, removing the lib, and project is running fine again.

I have try to remove licenses file but whit no luck.

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```

I have try to commpile picasso lib from site and from jar, same exception

```
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
```

or

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso) depends upon Picasso 2.5.2 and does not need `appcompat-v7` to build.

Comment: appcompat-v7 is needed for other parts in my project.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. `compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')` definitely will not work, as `appcompat-v7` is a library module, not a JAR. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'` should work, though.

Comment: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' works just fine whit my application, but if i add compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2', my app will end whit above exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in another Apache lib which obviously have conflicted whit picasso lib.